# Fast table recreation

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, peewee

I want a empty database for each test so I recreate the database each time. This is really slow. Is there a faster way?

```
my_dbmodule.DATABASE = ':memory:
my_dbmodule.db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')
my_dbmodule.db.connect()

my_dbmodule.db.drop_tables([DashboardConfig, MUT, Heartbeat,
                              Iteration, Log, Row,
                              DashboardConfigMUT], True)

my_dbmodule.db.create_tables([DashboardConfig, MUT, Heartbeat,
                                Iteration, Log, Row,
                                DashboardConfigMUT], True)
```

The only thing I came up with is the `with` syntax

```
with test_database(test_db, (MUT, Iteration)):
    do_something()
```

Which is to much code overhead for me, since it's needed in each test.

I use `from unittest import TestCase` to test, if it has any influence.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your tests in a transaction and rollback after each testcase, saving the expensive table creation. If you use a txn in your test-case of course you'll have to manually delete things, though.

You can enter the `test_database` context during the `setUp()` method on `TestCase`, and then call `__exit__` during `tearDown()`.

In short there are lots of ways, you just need to think outside the box.